# Proper way to prove correctness and termination of algorithm from transforming formulas

Tags: isabelle

I would like to prove the correctness and termination of a function/algorithm that transforms any first-order logic formula into its Negation Normal Form (NNF).
However, I do not even know how to start.Could anyone please help me?

I've tried to use the package FOL, but then I realized that I could not import Main to use "fun" command at the same time. Then I started with Main and proved a few equivalence rules using blast.

Now I need to create a function that transforms a first-order formula into its Negation Normal Form. I started with this:

fun toNNF :: "prop ==> prop" where ...

but this does not seems to work properly (Isabelle givens me the message: "Type unification error"). Any light here?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can start your definition of the function to convert a first-order formula into NNF, you might actually want to define a datatype that defines a type for first-order formulas, and for a correctness proof you need to first define a notion of equivalence of formulas as well as predicate for being in NNF.

Hope this helps,
René